# What are freer monads?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I heard this term a few times, but I still don't know what exactly is a so-called "Freer Monad". The name makes me think about Free Monads, but I don't see how they are actually related. There is some library I found on hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer, but the example out there didn't help me a lot.

I don't understand the idea at all, and therefore I don't see any good usecases for them. I also wonder what advantages they provide over free monads and classic mtl stacks.

Comment: Did you visit the links in the readme?

Comment: More examples are on [the related paper](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/more.pdf).

Comment: In short: a free monad turns any functor into a monad. A freer monad turns anything with kind `Type -> Type` into a monad, whether that thing is a functor or not.

Comment: Importantly, freer is used to provide an effect system as a library - a potential replacement for MTL style monad transformers and classes which are great but required N^2 instances and a full set of N new instances for every new monad.

Comment: @chepner you should post that as an answer, unless you're the close vote.

Comment: I am; this is too broad a question. (Also, that pithy comment is the pretty much the extent of my understanding of freer monads, and by itself it doesn't really answer any *one* of the 4 questions, let alone *all* 4.)

Comment: Should I edit out the question and leave just the "what is" part?

Comment: Freer Monads are an alternative to Monad transformer stacks. Effects are defined as data which could have multiple "interpretations". An interpretation performs the task and converts the Effect to the Freer monad. For example, a ReadText effect could read text from memory, file, database etc depending on the interpretation being used. This makes testing effortless. This also decouples business logic from implementation details neatly. Also different effects compose together beautifully when implemented with Freer monads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but i thought I'd answer it anyway just in  case

> what [...] is a so-called "Freer Monad"

according to the original paper [Freer Monads, More Extensible Effects](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/more.pdf) a "Freer Monad" is essentially a Free Monad without the necessary Functor constraint of a Free Monad.

A free monad is basically the essence of the monadic structure; the "smallest" thing that is still a monad. A very nice practial explanation approach [can be found in this article](https://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html). This article also shows that the "normal" free monad needs a Functor constraint.

However, it is often quite tedious adding the functor constraint in every function (and sometimes maybe even weird to implement), and as it turns out, by "moving the functor functionality" to an argument for the `Impure` constructor so that the implementing side can alter the type of the output itself (so without a general functor), it is possible to get rid of this constraint. This is done by using `GADTs`: (example from the `Freer Monads` paper)

```hs
data Free f a = Pure a
              | Impure (f (Free f a))

instance Functor f => Monad (Free f) where
```

becomes

```hs
data FFree f a where
    Pure :: a → FFree f a
    Impure :: f x → (x → FFree f a) → FFree f a

instance Monad (FFree f) where 
    [...]
    Impure fx k’ >>= k = Impure fx (k’ >>> k)
```

This basically lets the later implementation choose how to perform the `fmap` operation fixed [pun not intended] to the appropriate "output/wrapped type".
So the fundamental difference is essentially usability and generality.

As there was some confusion: `FFree` is the Freer monad and corresponds to `Eff` in the package `freer-simple`.

> good usecases for them

Freer monads, just as well as Free monads lend themselves for constructing DSLs.

consider for example a type

```
data Lang r where
    LReturn     :: Var -> Lang Int
    LPrint      :: IntExpr -> Lang ()
    LAssign     :: Var -> IntExpr -> Lang ()
    LRead       :: Var -> Lang Int
```

this tells me that there are a couple of operations to be performed in `Lang`: `return x` `print x` `assign x y` `read y`.

We use GADTs here so that we can also specify what output the individual actions are going to have. This comes in quite handy if we write functions in our DSL, because their output can be tpechecked.

adding some convenience functions (that can acutally be derived):

```hs
lReturn :: Member Lang effs
        => Var -> Eff effs Int
lReturn = send . LReturn

lPrint  :: Member Lang effs
        => IntExpr -> Eff effs ()
lPrint  = send . LPrint

lAssign :: Member Lang effs
        => Var -> IntExpr -> Eff effs ()
lAssign v  i = send $ LAssign v i

lRead   :: Member Lang effs
        => Var -> Eff effs Int
lRead   = send . LRead
```

(this is already written using `freer`)

now we can use them like this: (assuming that IntExpr contains Variables and Ints)

```hs
someFunctionPrintingAnInt = do
    lAssign (Var "a") (IE_Int 12)
    lPrint (IE_Var $ Var "a")
```

these functions now enable you to have a DSL that can be interpreted in different ways. All needed for this is an interpreter with a specific type for `effs` (which is ~~ a type level list of freer monad "instances)

so `freer` takes the idea of the freer monads and packs it into an effect system.

this interpreter could look something like this:

```hs
runLangPure :: Eff '[Lang] Int -> Either () Int -- [StateMap]
runLangPure program = fst . fst $
    run (runWriter (runState empty (runError (reinterpret3 go program))))
  where
    go :: Lang v -> Eff '[Error (), State StateMap, Writer [String]] v
    go (LReturn var) = get >>= go (Eval stmt) >>= tell . []
    go (LPrint expr) = do
        store <- get
        value <- evalM expr
        tell [show value]
    go (LAssign var expr) = do
        value <- evalM expr
        --modify state (change var) 
    go (LRead var) = do
        strValue <- getLine
        get >>= insert var (stringToInt strValue)
```

the `run...` part specifies the initial "state" of the monads. the `go` part is the interpreter itself, interpreting the different possible actions.

Note that one can use the functions `get` and `tell` in the same do block even though they are part of different monads, which brings us to

> I also wonder what advantages do they provide over free monads and classic mtl stacks.

the implementation allows to use monadic actions of different parts of the "monad stack" without `lift`ing.

**About the implementation:**

To understand this, we look at it from a high level of abstraction:
the auxiliary functions of our DSL are `send` to `Eff effs` where it is required that `Member Lang effs`.

So the `Member` constraint is just a way of declaing that `Lang` is in the type-level list `effs` in `Member Lang effs`. (basically typelevel `elem`)

The `Eff` monad has the functionality to "ask" the `Member`s of the type level list of monads whether they can handle the current value (remeber, the operations are just values that are intrepreted subsequently). if so their intrepretation is executed, if not, the question is handed off to the next monad in the list.

This becomes more intuitive and understandable when spending some time in the `freer-simple` code base.

Comment: in `Impure fx k’ >>= k = Impure fx (k’ >> k)`, isn't it that `k’ :: (x → FFree f a)` which means the `>>` in `(k’ >> k)` belongs to the functions monad, where the left argument is just ignored? `(undefined >> id) 1` returns `1`. what am I missing?

Comment: also, you use `Member` and `Eff` without introducing them. what are they? when you say `freer`, do you mean [`freer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer)? Hoogle only finds `Member` and `Eff` in the package `freer-simple` it seems.

Comment: @WillNess regarding your first comment: i made a typo copying the definition from the paper, you are right; the correct part is `k' >>> k` which is categorical composition.

Comment: `Member` is part of `polysemy`, `extensible-effects` and `freer-simple` this is just a way to express that `Lang` is in the type-level list `effs` in `Member Lang effs`. this is used to be polymorphic about the monadic constraints; e.g. you can embed something intended to be intrepreted in `[State Store]` also in `[State Store, Writer String]`

Comment: `Eff` is part of `extensible-effects` and `freer-simple`. it is essentially the `Freer` monad named `FFree` above

Comment: thanks. that `>>>`, in what category is it then? Kleisli? is it then equivalent to `>=>`? or is it used as an informal notation? --- re the references, probably worth editing them into the answer. also there are some typos which potentially harm readability somewhat. but overall, thanks for answering!

Comment: could it be said that freer monads are somehow _sums_ of monads, instead of their composition as the transformers try to be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234902/discussion-between-fabian-schneider-and-will-ness).

Comment: I am glad you answered this, even if was almost 2 years. The explanation is clear and informative, thank you for it! I am marking it as accepted, but I'd happily see other interpretations.